# Duplicating class in the object space object_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-engines

I having a strange issue where certain models in a rails engine I am using are getting duplicated in the object space.

```
(rdb:1) ObjectSpace.each_object(::Class).each { |klass| puts klass.to_s + ": " + klass.object_id.to_s if klass.to_s.eql?("DynamicFieldsets::Field") }
DynamicFieldsets::Field: 66866100
DynamicFieldsets::Field: 71836380
2479
```

When this happens, I cannot use is_a? or equality checks to test that an object is an instance of the Field class.  The problem only happens in development and it looks like it may be caused by cache_classes being off.  I think the object from the previous request is still in the object space but I am not sure how to remove it.

Comment: +1, this looks impossible. How can there be two objects bound to the same constant? What does `puts "#{klass.inspect}: #{klass.object_id}" if ...` output?

Comment: What sort class is `DynamicFieldsets::Field`? Where does it come from?

Comment: DynamicFieldsets::Field is an ActiveRecord::Base object coming from a rails engine.  When you inspect the classes in the object space, they are exactly the same except for object id.  Any method to check if the are equal will return true except for ones that check the object is, such as is_a? .

Comment: +1 That's strange... What @Matheus Moreira said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to reproduce with `remove_const`:

```
class X
  def self.foo
    "hello"
  end
end
first_x = X.new

Object.send :remove_const, :X
class X
  def self.foo
    "world"
  end
end
second_x = X.new

p first_x.class, first_x.class.object_id, second_x.class, second_x.class.object_id
  # => X, <an_id>, X, <another_id>
p first_x.class.foo, second_x.class.foo
  # => "hello", "world"
```

As you stated, you get this symptom only in development. When Rails reloads the classes, it simply calls `remove_const` on the defined classes, to force them to be reloaded (using `autoload`). [Here's the code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/04df7bb02c8a267ec7cd1c20ba20a49a24cffb2f/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb#L653). Rails will actually call `DynamicFieldsets::Field.before_remove_const` if it is defined, as explained [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/04df7bb02c8a267ec7cd1c20ba20a49a24cffb2f/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb#L511), how nice :-)

These should be garbage collected and you can trigger the GC with `GC.start`, but if you have instances of the old classes lying around (like `first_x` in my example), or subclasses, the old classes can not be garbage collected.

Note that `is_a?` should work fine, in the sense that new instances will be `kind_of?` and `is_a?` of the new class. In my example:

```
first_x.is_a? X  # => false
second_x.is_a? X # => true
```

This is the right behavior, as `X` refers to the new class, not the old class.